# I have a Procedure that it takes way too long, what can I do about it?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that store the GPS data from about 80 vehicle. This table keeps GPS transmission for each 30 seconds. I need to delete some data and keep the GPS transitions for each 60 seconds, at least. So I have the following procedure that read each row, for each det_id, and when the current row is less than 59 seconds from the previous row, then the the FLAG column is updated with '0'. After this I will delete those rows with FLAG = '0'.

The problem is this Procedure takes so long (about 40 hours for 3 million records).
I did an index with ts_id and ts_dh but it doesn't change so much.

How can improve this procedure?
Do I need to do a especial index?
Am I missing something in my procedure?

```
DECLARE

  WriteZero NUMBER:= 0;

    CURSOR CUR_TABLE_SOURCE IS
    SELECT 
           FLAG, ANT_TS_DH,ts_id,TS_DH,TS_DHS
    FROM TABLE_SOURCE
    where ts_id = in_ts_id
    order by ts_id, TS_DH;

    V_count number:=0;  
    V_Ant number:=0;  

    V_TABLESOURCE_REC CUR_TABLE_SOURCE%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

      OPEN CUR_TABLE_SOURCE;  ---  for update;
      loop
      FETCH CUR_TABLE_SOURCE INTO V_TABLESOURCE_REC;
      EXIT WHEN CUR_TABLE_SOURCE%NOTFOUND;

      V_count := V_count + 1;

      Begin

        IF V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH is null then
            UPDATE TABLE_SOURCE SET  
                   FLAG = '1'           
            WHERE ANT_TS_DH = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH
            AND   ts_id = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ts_id
            AND   TS_DHS = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.TS_DHS;  
            commit;
            V_Ant :=1; 
        ELSE 
                IF V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH + 59/86400 >= V_TABLESOURCE_REC.TS_DH THEN 
                        IF V_Ant = 1 THEN
                            UPDATE TABLE_SOURCE SET  
                                   FLAG = '0'  --  delete data with flag = 0
                            WHERE ANT_TS_DH = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH
                            AND   ts_id = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ts_id
                            AND   TS_DHS = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.TS_DHS;
                            V_Ant :=0; 
                            commit;
                        ELSE
                            UPDATE TABLE_SOURCE SET  
                                    FLAG = '1' --  keep data with flag = 0
                            WHERE ANT_TS_DH = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH
                            AND   ts_id = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ts_id
                            AND   TS_DHS = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.TS_DHS; 
                            V_Ant :=1; 
                            commit;   
                        End If;       
                ELSE
                    UPDATE TABLE_SOURCE SET  
                           FLAG = '1'
                    WHERE ANT_TS_DH = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ANT_TS_DH
                    AND   ts_id = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.ts_id
                    AND   TS_DHS = V_TABLESOURCE_REC.TS_DHS; 
                    V_Ant :=1; 
                    commit;   
                End If;     
        End If;  

        End;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE CUR_TABLE_SOURCE;

 COMMIT;

 END;
```

This is the table_source:

```
TS_ID TS_DH                 LATI       LONG
----- --------------------- ---------- ----------
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.05.09 AM  11.42341   -81.95251
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.05.39 AM  11.42344   -81.92435
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.06.09 AM  11.43567   -81.85355
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.06.39 AM  11.47851   -81.95246
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.07.10 AM  11.45123   -81.63451
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.07.40 AM  11.43451   -81.95351
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.08.10 AM  11.45251   -81.46785
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.08.40 AM  11.45678   -81.95551
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.09.10 AM  11.43451   -81.93241
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.09.40 AM  11.45456   -81.95251
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.10.10 AM  11.42890   -81.95451
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.15.40 AM  11.43451   -81.95351
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.16.10 AM  11.45251   -81.46785
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.16.40 AM  11.45678   -81.95551
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.17.10 AM  11.43451   -81.93241
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.17.40 AM  11.45456   -81.95251
 3412 15-DEC-16 11.18.10 AM  11.42890   -81.95451
```

Comment: Not enough info to say.  Try these things:  1) setup and run DMBS_PROFILER package to profile the procedure.  2) If you have AWR licensed, run an AWR report.  3) Look in V$sqlarea for the queries, and see their performance.  You can then use the sql_id to find the explain plans with DBMS_XPLAN.  Why are you doing commits in the loop??  That is bad, bad, bad!  Also, you may be able to just refactor this whole things using a MERGE statement.  Much more efficient. Row-by-Row processing = slow-by-slow.

Comment: Hard to tell, how many records does the cursor have to go through? If its a lot cutting the number down would be good. Other thing that leaped out was the order by in the select for the cursor, do you have a suitable index for that? Get some stats like @OldProgrammer suggested.

Comment: It sounds like you have 6 million GPS location entries (every 30 seconds) and you want a result that essentially has half (every 60 seconds).  Can you do this instead.  Select the records you want to keep into a new table, then swap the old data and and the new data in via a partition swap.  Your table/data model may not be ready for this now, but this would be the quickest way to handle what you are trying to do so it may be worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did that, I changed the procedure to update the selected records to a new table and the process went way faster, like 20 minutes.

Comment: @Rodrick It sounds like progress; but 20 mins for 6million rows still sounds pretty slow. Can you share your solution?